# Unable to flag as spam after flagging for moderator attention

Tags: support, flags, spam

I flagged a post for moderator attention. Soon after that (about a minute) the OP changed the whole post into spam. Then I tried to flag the post as spam however I got the dialog that I had already flagged this post for moderator attention.

How come I'm not allowed to flag a post as spam if I flagged it for moderator attention? I distinctly remember being able to do it in the other direction. (Flag spam then flag for moderator attention)

Comment: Because then people would flag spam as spam *and* custom to try and garner a bonus helpful flag, and we'd start declining all of them we see because that's an abuse of the system, and they'd start complaining that their flags are being declined... You get where this is going...

Comment: @animuson did that change in the flag overhaul awhile back?

Comment: No,it's long been the rule that you can only have one pending flag on a post at a time. Once your custom flag (or whatever flag you used) is handled, you are free to flag the post again if it warrants further moderator attention. But if it's spam, it won't, because it'll be deleted and locked.

Comment: @animuson My flagging history (and my memory) seem to suggest that I was able to flag as spam then for moderator attention. However I don't want to test this out on a random post.

Comment: @animuson could it be possible to let us _retract_ the custom flag and post a new one?

Comment: @fdi it did used to he that way > 1 year ago.

Comment: It has been flagged. A moderator will look at it. She'll see that it's spam, and take care of it. Your flag will be valid. I don't see the problem. Why over-complicate things?

Comment: @CodyGray The only reason to over-complicate things is to remove the post from the front page faster. However I just tried flagging in the other direction and it didn't work so I must be remembering things wrong.

Comment: Actually front page is wrong in that previous comment it should just be remove/delete the post faster